# Desiring something possible with the help of an unseen force

Tags: grammar

To get beauty is my desire. But I will get it only if some other force helps me to get this. And, of course getting beauty is possible too. Now in such case which of the following fits best?

> I wish I got beauty.

OR

> I hope I get beauty.

Answer (score 1):

"I wish" is usually used to express a condition that is contrary to fact. For example:

> I wish I were beautiful.

Note the use of "were" instead of "was." When you're expressing something that's theoretical or contrary to fact, you use the subjunctive. In this case, that means you use "were" instead of "was."

Another example:

> If she were beautiful, she wouldn't have worried.

"I hope" is usually used to express something that is possible, and isn't known to be contrary to fact. For example, a blind person might say,

> "I hope I'm beautiful."